# When I try run a .py file in my terminal it doesn’t work

Tags: python

I’ve created a .py file and saved it to my desktop.
When I open terminal, I type cd desktop(which does the obvious)
After this I type python (file name).py, then when I hit enter it just goes back the the desktop command line again and doesn’t run the file.

Any ideas?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/global/uk-en/Desktop-Graphics-Cards/Subtegory/ID-48?nm_mc=KNC-GoogleukAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleukAdwords-_-Sitelink-UK-_-VGA-Cards-_-Global&gclid=CjwKCAjwh5qLBhALEiwAioods8nGbLNkDI5dBNTHrJ1pprzHJDzoMXHlswOapX8G82IbGUhk1FK9gRoCczsQAvD_BwE'
#opens up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs each product
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item- container"})
for container in containers:
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]
    title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    shipping_container = container.findAll("li",    {"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

    print("brand: " + brand)
    print("product_name: " + product_name)
    print("shipping: " + shipping)
```

Comment: What sort of output are you expecting ? Are you printing anything to the console?

Comment: If you are using a Mac or Linux machine, you need to use the `python3` command instead of `python`

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Also, if the python file doesn't contain any code, nothing will happen.

Comment: what's the code? share the code

Comment: I’m coding along to this video https://youtu.be/XQgXKtPSzUI I’m at 28:55

Comment: Can you just put a print right on top of your script and see if that prints anything.

Comment: it does print anything in sublime, but when I copy the code over the juypter notebook the print statement works at the top

Comment: im running macOS 11.6 currently

Comment: @LiamMoore93 do you mean it *doesn't* print anything?  What do you mean by 'in sublime'?  In any case, try writing a very basic python program (`print("hello")`), saving it somewhere, and running that.

Comment: If your .py working well in pycharm or other ide and not working only in window command line then open Dos command as administrator and then go to file location for example desktop then go to desktop then before to give file name type python then file name Eg: Desktop>python/filename.py

Comment: Did you check your python version?

Answer (score 1):

First, please confirm whether you installed python correctly.
After installing python, you should set environment variable on windows OS.

- Path
- python program installation location.
  for example, 3.11 and 3.11/scripts.
  After setting path, please check " python -v".

Answer (score 0):

```
#grabs each product
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item- container"})
print(containers)
for container in containers:
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]
```

That will show that your containers list is empty like:

`[]`

thus nothing gets looped in the for, so nothing to be printed out.  So either you can't collect the page, or the findAll isn't finding the divs.  Start troubleshooting by printing out the actual results of collecting the page (perhaps you are blocked, the website doesn't like spiders, etc.)  Good luck!